# Playing 2 audio files one after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I've already looked on the few similar questions on here and can't find anything relevant. I have 2 audio files. The first plays through when the page loads, and it works fine. I want the 2nd audio file to play as soon as the first one ends and I also need the 2nd file too loop indefinitely. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
<body>
<audio autoplay id="audio_1" src="./audio1.wav"></audio>
<audio loop id="audio_2" src="./audio_2.wav"></audio>
</body>
```

And the javascript:

```
var audio = document.getElmentById("audio_1");
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
audio.src = "./audio_2.wav";
audio.play();
});
```

Like I said, the 1st file plays fine, but then the 2nd file doesn't play at all. Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try creating two vars :

```
var audio = document.getElmentById("audio_1");
var audio2 = document.getElmentById("audio_2");
audio2.pause();
audio.addEventListener("ended", function() {
   audio_2.play();
});
```

EDIT: you had typos errors in "getElement"

here is the new code

```
var audio = document.getElementById("audio_1");
var audio2 = document.getElementById("audio_2");
audio2.pause();
audio.addEventListener("ended", function () {
 audio2.play();
});
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same issue. Maybe I coded it wrong. My javascript knowledge is pretty limited. Would it be possible to get a jsfiddle example?

Comment: I am putting the javascript inside the header tags. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Just put the new javascript I gave you inside `<script> </script>` before the `</body>`

Comment: Still nothing. I think it maybe something to do with the audio tags, just clueless what to change

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the second .wav as a JS varibale, then setting a timeout for its trigger, so that once the first one has finished, the second one will begin. Once you have done that, you just need to write the loop code for the second .wav.